# Table column text-overflow ellipsis ( width in % )

Tags: css, html

I have this markup for mobile.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td style="width:60%">
<div class="ellipsis">
Test bla bla
</div>
</td>
<td style="width:40%">
</td>
</tr>
```

**CSS**

```
.ellipsis { 
width : 100%;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
-o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
word-break: break-all;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

The truncation doesn't work as desired, instead the column expands depending on content.

Table-Layout : fixed makes both the columns equal.

Any suggestions ? Thanks.

Comment: My advice is to not use a table.

Comment: Yep, Brett. After lots of searching and all, I dropped table and using ul, it works like charm.

Comment: Can I get a point for my comment? :P

Answer (score 5):

Please use the following css to make css3 truncation work with tables

```
table {
   width: 200px; /*specify a width*/
   table-layout:fixed;
}
```

The property "table-layout:fixed" seems important to work text truncation for any block level elements inside a table.

Comment: table-layout:fixed; is making the columns equal in size if width is given in %. Even the table width is in %, fluid design.